# Can objects exit a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, relativistic-jets

I read [an article](http://mysteriousuniverse.org/2016/03/astronomers-measure-mysterious-object-leaving-black-hole/) claiming that an object had been observed to be ejected from a black hole.

This was the newest article I could find published on it but they still seem uncertain what the object was or how it could be ejected. Are there any updates to what may the object have been or how it got out of the black hole? Does matter leaving a black hole violate any theories?

Comment: Beyond event horizon, the physics is not clear at all. At singularity, the laws of physics no more holds good, as said by Stephen Hawking.

Answer (score 2):

That's just a very poorly written article. Nothing was observed to exit from inside the event horizon. There was a high energy event that launched a flare from **near** the BH. The event is unexplained, but doesn't obviously violate any known laws of physics.

Comment: Oh really? I found several articles that word it the same way.

Comment: @Celeritas That doesn't make them right. It's also not all that surprising: they all worked from the same press release, perhaps that was also poorly worded, or they may have worked from a story published by one media outlet. Most science writers do not base the bulk of their writing on their reading the actual technical article(s). Many do read the article, of course, but the press release is meant to serve as a guide to why the story is interesting, in simpler terms.

Answer (score 2):

Well, plenty of black holes show jets of highly energetic gas or plasma coming out perpendicular to their rotation plane, seemingly out of the hole. It's just accreting highly energetic gas that's spiraling into the black hole but can not make it in, much of it does but much of it is expelled out. It is not from the hole, just the energetics works out that way from the accretion disk. See it in [1].

Sagittarius A which the figure in the article shows is one of those, they call them flares, same thing. Happens to most black holes with large enough accretion disks. It's been known for quite a while. The article is printing old news

Nothing can come out of black holes.

Reference 1:  http://kipac-web.stanford.edu/research/blackholes